# Displaying words in a Trie

Tags: c, dictionary, trie, tree-traversal

I have created a trie which stores words from a dictionary, I am trying to create a function which displays all the words starting with a set of characters, e.g. if I search 'car' words like 'carpet', 'cart' will be printed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct TrieNode
{
char key; //value in node
struct TrieNode* child; //stores child of nodes
struct TrieNode* sibling; //stores sibling
};

struct TrieNode* TrieNodeConstructor(char key)
{
    struct TrieNode* node; //creates pointer for trie
    node = malloc(sizeof(struct TrieNode)); //dynamically assigns memory to trie

node->key = key; //sets value to input

//child and sibling are initially NULL
node->child = NULL;
node->sibling = NULL;

return node;
}


void TrieDestructor(struct TrieNode* node) //deletes node
{
    if (node->sibling != NULL) //checks if sibling node is empty
    {
        TrieDestructor(node->sibling); //frees sibling node
    }

    if (node->child != NULL) //checks if child node is empty
    {
        TrieDestructor(node->child); //frees child node
    }

    free(node); //frees node
}

void insert(struct TrieNode* node, char* str, int value)
{
    if(str[value]=='\0') //if input string is empty
    {
        node = TrieNodeConstructor('#'); //root node
        return;
    }

    if(node==NULL) //if node is empty
    {
        node = TrieNodeConstructor(str[value]); //recursion
        insert(node->child, str, value+1); //increments value and inserts
    }

    if(node->key == str[value]) //if the key matches the value
    {
        insert(node->child, str, value+1); //insert child below node
    }
    else //if the character is not already in the trie
    {
        insert(node->sibling, str, value+1); //it becomes a sibling
    }

}

int search(struct TrieNode* node, char* str, int value)
{
    if(node==NULL) //node is empty
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if(node->key=='#' && str[value]=='\0') //root node
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if((node->key!='#' &&  str[value]=='\0') || (node->key=='#' && str[value]!='\0')) //Empty
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if(node->key == str[value]) //if key matches with input
    {
        return search(node->child,str,value+1); //search next letter in word
    }
    else
    {
        return search(node->sibling,str,value); //searches through next letter
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can modify the search function (or create another) to return the pointer to the end of search node (e.g. return pointer to `r` when searched for `car`). From there on, just do a recursive DFS to the rest of the tree while printing the strings.